# How to detect android application installed or not through web page, if not installed then stay there or redirect to apps store

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

When I check the application installed or not using custom URL with JavaScript then application jump to the application but 
if app is not installed then redirect to blank page myschema://details?parameters if installed then working fine and open both link that i redirect in my code play store as well as custom URL that I configured in android apps.

Below is my code (same logic I implemeted in iOS app and it's working fine)

```
var now = new Date().valueOf();
setTimeout(function(){
     if (new Date().valueOf() - now > 100) return;
      window.location = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.apps.package";//play store URL.
},25);
window.location = "myschema://details?parameters";//custom url
```

Is there any way to jump on custom URL if not installed apps then redirect to play store URL?